# Execution never jumps to DMA IRQHandler in stm32f4105x

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, dma, hal

I'm trying to get a sequence of 1000 samples from ADC1 of STM32f4105VC of STM32f401c-disco, using the DMA transactions. I want the DMA to generate an interrupt when the transfer is complete and to stop there so that no data is overwritten. Here is the code:

```
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define M 5
#define F_S 42000000
#define LOG_SIZE 1000
#define MEAS_PERIODS 1
#define DMA_BUFFER_SIZE 1000
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
__IO uint16_t uhADCxConvertedValue[DMA_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
__IO uint32_t uwADCxConvertedVoltage = 0;
double voltage=0;
double S=0, rms=0, F=0; // S quadratic sums, rms - the rms value, F the frequency
uint32_t N; //number of samplings
double unscaled_voltage=0;
uint32_t max_N=0, steady_N = 0;

typedef char MyString[50];
MyString Log[LOG_SIZE];



/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
static void ADC_Config(void);


void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(DMA_GetITStatus(DMA_STREAMx,DMA_IT_TCIF0)!=RESET) {
   DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA_STREAMx,DMA_STREAMx,DMA_IT_TCIF0|DMA_IT_HTIF0);
    }
}


/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /*!< At this stage the microcontroller clock setting is already configured, 
       this is done through SystemInit() function which is called from startup
       files (startup_stm32f40_41xxx.s/startup_stm32f427_437xx.s/startup_stm32f429_439xx.s)
       before to branch to application main. 
       To reconfigure the default setting of SystemInit() function, refer to
       system_stm32f4xx.c file
     */



    double R = 3.0/0xfff; //conversion ratio
    double dc_offset = 1.5;
    double ac_scaling = 0.0022;
    double mv_filter[M]={0};//moving average filter
  uint8_t wave_pos=0; //0 upper half wave, 1 lower half wave
    uint32_t i=0;
    uint8_t i_period = 1;
  /* ADC configuration */
  ADC_Config();

  /* Start ADC Software Conversion */ 
//   ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADCx);
    ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADCx);
  while (1) {}
}

static void ADC_Config(void)
{
  ADC_InitTypeDef       ADC_InitStructure;
  ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStructure;
  DMA_InitTypeDef       DMA_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef      GPIO_InitStructure;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef            NVIC_InitStructure;

  /* Enable ADCx, DMA and GPIO clocks ****************************************/ 
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(ADCx_CHANNEL_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);  
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(ADCx_CLK, ENABLE);

    /* Enable the DMA2 Stream0 Global Interrupt (to handle the Transfer Complete Interrupt TCIF) */
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Stream0_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

  /* DMA2 Stream0 channel15 configuration **************************************/
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_CHANNELx;  
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)ADCx_DR_ADDRESS;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&uhADCxConvertedValue[0];
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = DMA_BUFFER_SIZE;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;         
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
  DMA_Init(DMA_STREAMx, &DMA_InitStructure);
  DMA_Cmd(DMA_STREAMx, ENABLE);

  /* Configure ADC1 Channel15 pin as analog input ******************************/
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_PIN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL ;
  GPIO_Init(GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* ADC Common Init **********************************************************/
  ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
  ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
  ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_1;
  ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;
  ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStructure);

  /* ADC1 Init ****************************************************************/
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
  ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 1;
  ADC_Init(ADCx, &ADC_InitStructure);

  /* ADC1 regular channel15 configuration **************************************/
  ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADCx, ADC_CHANNEL, 1, ADC_SampleTime_3Cycles);

//  /* Enable DMA request after last transfer (Single-ADC mode) */
  ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADCx, ENABLE);

//   /* Enable ADC1 DMA */
  ADC_DMACmd(ADCx, ENABLE);

  /* Enable ADC1 */
  ADC_Cmd(ADCx, ENABLE);

    DMA_ITConfig(DMA_STREAMx,DMA_IT_TC,ENABLE);
}
```

When I debug the program after some time the DMA stops and the flags `TCIF0` and `HTIF0` are set in the the register `DMA_LISR`, though a breakpoint in the `DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler` function is only once activated. Why?

Comment: Is the reason you are using DMA that the program was too slow to respond without it, or is it just to free up the CPU? In case of the latter, ignore this comment. In case of the former, a solution with 1000 samples followed by an interrupt means that the interrupt will still have to be handled. And the DMA interrupt is likely more intricate than a simple ADC interrupt would have been. So if your program already couldn't handle the ADC interrupt, it will not be able to handle the DMA interrupt either.

Comment: It's the second case.

Comment: By the way the first case for this code is even in theory not possible :).

Comment: Are you sure about `DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&uhADCxConvertedValue;`? It seems odd to pass a pointer to the address of the measured values. I would expect this to invoke a lot of undefined behavior.

Comment: @mvds I don't understand your question. DMA_Memory0BaseAddr is expecting an address pointing the location where the DMA is going to refere. What do you suggest to pass?

Comment: I would pass `uhADCxConvertedValue`, without `&`, that is the address of the first value of the array. (Or `&uhADCxConvertedValue[0]`, which is the same)

Comment: @mvds ok got your point. You are right about that. It's already a known thing. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but should we fix it here, for anybody coming by, looking for example code (like me)?

Comment: We could fix it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those facing similar problem. When the DMA_IT_TCIF0 was triggered simultaneously there was an overrun interrupt in the ADC. Therefore the program needs to recover from that according to the sequence described in the RM0090 page 403, 13.8.1 Using the DMA. Here is the updated IRQHandler:

```
void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {
    if(DMA_GetITStatus(DMA_STREAMx,DMA_IT_TCIF0)!=RESET) {
        //clear the ADC->CR2 DDS and DMA flag to disable further DMA requests
        ADCx->CR2 &= ~(ADC_CR2_DDS|ADC_CR2_DMA);
        //do processing
        DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA_STREAMx,DMA_IT_TCIF0|DMA_IT_HTIF0);
        //abjust the DMA NDTR counter
        DMA_STREAMx->NDTR = (uint32_t)DMA_BUFFER_SIZE;
        DMA_STREAMx->CR |= (uint32_t)DMA_SxCR_EN;
        //set the DMA bit
        ADCx->CR2 |= (ADC_CR2_DMA|ADC_CR2_DDS);
        //clear the overload
        ADCx->SR &= ~(ADC_SR_OVR|ADC_SR_STRT);
        //start the ADC
        ADCx->CR2 |= (uint32_t)ADC_CR2_SWSTART;
    }
    ;
}
```

Apart from that everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't configuring the DMA interrupt correctly. You need to send the IT config function `DMA2_Stream0`. Change the line `DMA_ITConfig(DMA_CHANNELx, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);` to `DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream0, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);`.

Comment: This was a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's defined in the startup_stmf4xx.S file and declared at the correct vector spot.

```
    .long    DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler           // DMA2 Stream 0
```

Comment: This is so. The DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler is called once, but no more.

Comment: Are you handling the DMA Half transfer interrupt? clearing HTIF0

Comment: Now yes. But it's not helping. I'll update the code.

Comment: I see the ADC is in continuous conversion mode, there's another field in that ADC_InitStructure called DMAContinuousRequests.  Look in stm32fxx_hal_adc.c at ADC_Init

Comment: I don't see such field in the ADC_InitTypeDef declaration. Are you referring the stm32f4xx_adc.h file?

Comment: Look in the ADC control reg 2.

Bit 1 CONT: Continuous conversion

This bit is set and cleared by software. If it is set, conversion takes place continuously until it is cleared.

0: Single conversion mode

1: Continuous conversion mode

Comment: Yes I see it's definition in stm32f4xx_had_adc.h as well, however the target I'm looking at is the 401RE Nucleo board and the 401 Discovery boards.  Look into the .c file to see if that bit is set in the CR2 register.

Comment: How about a breakpoint at HAL_DMA_IRQHandler to see what the hdma structure contains, or if there's an error callback?

Comment: It should be set by the ADC_Init. But why that will make a difference?

Comment: HAL_DMA_IRQHandler is not defined in the startup_stm32f40xx.s.

Comment: There could be transfer error, fifo error, or dma error interrupts being set.

Comment: I think we are going away from the problem. I see OVR flag set in the ADC_SR register. I think the adc or the dma should be reenabled but how?

Comment: In my project DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(...) calls the HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(..) function.  I've defined it in my project and over-ridden the `weak` reference in the code.

Comment: Could be. But I don't find such function anywhere in the library.

Comment: Do you have stm32fxx_hal_dma.c in your project?  It should be defined there.

Comment: Negative. No stm32fxx_hal_dma.c.

Comment: Maybe get an updated Cube from STM. I have both  STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.3.0\Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Inc\stm32f4xx_hal_dma.h and STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.3.0\Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c

Comment: I'm not using Cube. I'm working the the library only, and avoid any high-level stuffs any time whenever rational. Btw. I've just solved the issue. I'm going to post the answer later. Thanks for the contribution.